# spark function : date_format doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use : org.apache.spark.sql.functions's date_format to format a given string Date but it doesn't work :
here is the code that I execute :

```
val data = Seq("20190413","20190310","20190923").toDF
data.show 
    +--------+
    |   value|
    +--------+
    |20190413|
    |20190310|
    |20190923|
    +--------+
val data2=data.withColumn("date",date_format(col("value"),"yyyyMMdd"))
data2.show
    +--------+----+
    |   value|date|
    +--------+----+
    |20190413|null|
    |20190310|null|
    |20190923|null|
    +--------+----+
```

from the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) it is said that :

> date_format(dateExpr: Column, format: String): Column
>   Converts a date/timestamp/**string** to a value of string in the format specified by the date format given by the second argument.
>
> See java.text.SimpleDateFormat for valid date and time format patterns.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using strings, they should be ISO-formatted dates. The format you specify is applied to output.

```
scala> val data=Seq("2019-04-13","2019-03-10","2019-09-23").toDF
scala> val data2=data3.
     |           withColumn("date",date_format(col("value"),"yyyyMMdd")).
     |           withColumn("date-US",date_format(col("value"),"MM/dd/yyyy"))
scala> data2.show()
+----------+--------+----------+
|     value|    date|   date-US|
+----------+--------+----------+
|2019-04-13|20190413|04/13/2019|
|2019-03-10|20190310|03/10/2019|
|2019-09-23|20190923|09/23/2019|
+----------+--------+----------+
```

**EDIT**

If your string representation of dates is in some other format, you will probably need to convert them to proper date type, and then format as you like. For example:

```
scala> val data2=data.withColumn("date-US",date_format(to_date(col("value"),"yyyyMMdd"),"MM/dd/yyyy"))
scala> data2.show()
+--------+----------+
|   value|   date-US|
+--------+----------+
|20190413|04/13/2019|
|20190310|03/10/2019|
|20190923|09/23/2019|
+--------+----------+
```

Format used in `to_date()` function here is the **input** format.

Comment: oK I see, so it will not work if the string date has an other format than IOS

Comment: @aName Not without some added string-date-string muddling.

Answer (score 0):

> In Spark you can use unix_timestamp and from_unixtime

```
scala> data.withColumn("tt",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("value"),"yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy/MM/dd")).show

+--------+----------+
|   value|        tt|
+--------+----------+
|20190413|2019/04/13|
|20190310|2019/03/10|
|20190923|2019/09/23|
+--------+----------+
```

this is a proper way to achieving the desired output.I